# Long Text in Label of Section Header is not showing correctly

Tags: uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I have a textLabel in table view header section in a Question/Answer app. When the user tap on Question, answer is shown and on tap again answer will hide.

I am displaying Question in header section but if the question text is long the text is not getting adjusted nor is it wrapping into more lines.

Comment: Please clear your question what do you want to do and what you have done so far?

Comment: Please add  your code snippet where the Question text is handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your question is not clear enough but so far I have understood that you want to make a `UITableView` which is `Group TableView`. If I am not wrong then you want to make every `section` as a question container and `Row or Cell` will be the answer of that question. In one word you want to make an expandable `UITableViewCell`. If so then you can check following link

https://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/

https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-how-to-build-a-table-view-with-collapsible-sections-96badf3387d0

https://mobikul.com/create-expandable-table-view-swift/

Now your second problem was `HeaderText` which is not taking numberOfLines .To solve this problem you can use the delegate method of `UITableView` which is `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?` where you can add your `UILabel` and set your `numberOfLines` of the text.

AND `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat` which will contain the height of the `UITableView` section header. For making dynamic header you have to calculate the `UILabel` height and set it as a section header height.

Feel free to ask any questions.

Happy Coding!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! but if I add an label on viewForHeaderInSection than tap gesture on section stops working and if I take tap on label than also its not working.As I want to expand the cell when I tap on section.Pls help!!

Comment: https://github.com/jeantimex/ios-swift-collapsible-table-section Please follow every single step of this code and I thing it should work.

Comment: Or In spite of using label you can add button which will contain your label text and make one function of that button action which will receive the index of the cell as a parameter so that you can understand which cell is active.